# Why mysql datetime minus not correct?

Tags: mysql, datetime

This SQL.

It is very obvious that the seconds should be 86400 for one day. Why MYSQL return 1000000?

```
select str_to_date('2021-04-24 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') - str_to_date('2021-04-23 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as seconds  from dual;
+---------+
| seconds |
+---------+
| 1000000 |
+---------+
```

Comment: Str_to_date is redundant in this context

Comment: @Strawberry: The output without `str_to_date()` is different, so it is not redundant.   (`select '2021-04-24 00:00:00'-'2021-04-23 00:00:00';`  output: `0` )

Comment: @Luuk How is that different? (Think carefully before answering)

Comment: If using `str_to_date()` the output is different. So the usage of this function has influence on the output. This makes it not `redundant`, because that would mean it is useless.  In this context the question is asked why the output is `1000000`, A wrong answer would be "leave out `str_to_date()`", because then the question changes to "why is the output `0`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting two dates does not do what you're expecting here. What it does is format the dates as `yyyyMMddHHmmss` and subtract them as normal numbers, as in;

```
  20210424000000
- 20210423000000
----------------
         1000000
```

What you instead want is the [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function;

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(
  SECOND,
  '2021-04-23 00:00:00',
  '2021-04-24 00:00:00'
) AS seconds;

+---------+
| seconds |
+---------+
| 86400   |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Because difference is

```
1 day
00 hours
00 minutes
00 seconds
```

If you try

```
select str_to_date('2021-05-25 00:04:05', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') - str_to_date('2021-04-23 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as seconds;
```

Result is 102000405 , that means

```
1 month
2 days
0 hours
4 minutes 
5 seconds
```

For seconds use UNIX_TIMESTAMP

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-04-24 00:00:00') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-04-23 00:00:00') as seconds;
```